# How can i disable the page My account - woocommerce for the users how are not login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce in my website. I want to disable (hide) the link My account in the menu when a user is not login. So when the user is connected the link be active.

Merce in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you doing our custom template then you can use simple condition

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.wp_logout_url( home_url() ).'"><span class="icon-logout"></span> Logout</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_home_url().'/my-account"><span class="icon-gearbox"></span> Account</a></li>';
}
else {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_home_url().'" class="login-pop"><span class="icon-login"></span> Login</a></li>';
}
```

?>

Comment: I use Divi theme and the content is added automatically in the header menu. Maybe i have to modify the header.php file.

Comment: Its not free theme so I can't download and check how they including links to menu, maybe a hook or nav_walker

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the user is logged in with PHP and if he is not, remove the `a` tag with the `href` attribute that ends with **my-account/**, using JavaScript.

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
echo <<<EOD
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => document.querySelector('a[href$="my-account/"]').remove())  
</script>
EOD;
}
```

Comment: @GerganaKostadinova you're welcome! If this answer helped you, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the link in the menu using CSS. First, make sure that your theme adds the "logged-in" class to the body element of your site. If it does, carry on:

Click on Customise in your admin menu, select Menus and then the name of your menu. Go to the menu item for "My account" and in the CSS Classes field, type "hide-me".

Now go to the Additional CSS panel in the Customiser and add this CSS:

`body:not(.logged-in) .hide-me { display: none !important; }`

*NOTE: This is all in theory as you have not provided a link to your site, so I can't see the HTML or CSS.*

Comment: if theme supports body class, there is a free plugin which adds body class (https://wordpress.org/plugins/browser-body-classes-with-shortcodes/)